# IN operation in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a collection with all the ids. I want to create a hibernate criteria where I pass the collection and get the results matching all the values in the list with a joined tables.

Similar to a WHERE IN operation in sql.

```
select * from Employee e, dept d where d.id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Restriction` for your purpose:

```
Criteria c = ... // get Employee criteria here
c.createAlias("dept", "d");
c.add(Restrictions.in("d.id", ids));
```

Comment: Actually I wanted a criteria for a join query

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks Sergey!!